# PHP: while loops how to do this

Tags: php, pdo, while-loop

I wish to make a "Previous events: ...." where it grabs the events that has date before now() `WHERE date < unix_timestamp(NOW())` and Upcoming events: where it grabs the events that has later than current `date > unix_timestamp(NOW())`

I got to this:

```
$grabEvents = $connect->prepare("SELECT eID FROM discos_events_guests WHERE uID =:user");
$grabEvents->bindValue(":user", $profile_id);
$grabEvents->execute();
if($grabEvents->rowCount()>0){
echo "<strong>Previous events:</strong><br>";
    while($event = $grabEvents->fetch()){
    $eID = $event["eID"];
    $grabEvent = $connect->prepare("SELECT title FROM discos_events WHERE id=:eid AND date < unix_timestamp(NOW())");
    $grabEvent->bindValue(":eid", $eID);
    $grabEvent->execute();
    $grabEvent = $grabEvent->fetch();
    echo $grabEvent["title"]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Works just fine, and grabs the previous events well. How should I do grab the Upcoming events then, in this code? I tried having another query inside the while but it gets all messed up because it checks two and yes, didnt turn out how i wish.

How can i do this?

Comment: i guess you should do this in one query to your database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start you need to optimise your query instead of repeatedly querying within a while loop do this instead:

```
SELECT deg.eID, de.title
FROM discos_events_guests deg
JOIN discos_events de on de.id = deg.eID
WHERE uID =:user
  AND date < unix_timestamp(NOW())
```

For example to get the previous you would do:

```
$grabEvents = $connect->prepare("SELECT de.title
    FROM discos_events_guests deg
    JOIN discos_events de on de.id = deg.eID
    WHERE uID =:user
      AND date < unix_timestamp(NOW())");
$grabEvents->bindValue(":user", $profile_id);
$grabEvents->execute();
if($grabEvents->rowCount()>0){
    while($event = $grabEvents->fetch()){
        echo $event["title"]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Then just execute the same again for the upcoming query:

```
$grabEvents = $connect->prepare("SELECT de.title
    FROM discos_events_guests deg
    JOIN discos_events de on de.id = deg.eID
    WHERE uID =:user
      AND date > unix_timestamp(NOW())");
$grabEvents->bindValue(":user", $profile_id);
$grabEvents->execute();
if($grabEvents->rowCount()>0){
    while($event = $grabEvents->fetch()){
        echo $event["title"]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just start another loop, like:

```
$grabEvents = $connect->prepare("SELECT eID FROM discos_events_guests WHERE uID =:user");
$grabEvents->bindValue(":user", $profile_id);
$grabEvents->execute();
if($grabEvents->rowCount()>0){
echo "<strong>Previous events:</strong><br>";
    while($event = $grabEvents->fetch()){
    $eID = $event["eID"];
    $grabEvent = $connect->prepare("SELECT title FROM discos_events WHERE id=:eid AND date < unix_timestamp(NOW())");
    $grabEvent->bindValue(":eid", $eID);
    $grabEvent->execute();
    $grabEvent = $grabEvent->fetch();
    echo $grabEvent["title"]."<br>";
    }

echo "<strong>Upcoming Events:</strong><br>";
    while($event = $grabEvents->fetch()){
    $eID = $event["eID"];
    $grabEvent = $connect->prepare("SELECT title FROM discos_events WHERE id=:eid AND date > unix_timestamp(NOW())");
    $grabEvent->bindValue(":eid", $eID);
    $grabEvent->execute();
    $grabEvent = $grabEvent->fetch();
    echo $grabEvent["title"]."<br>";
    }
}
```

At least, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Though @Treffynnon is correct, the query should be optimized. Getting 1000 results 1 time is more efficient then getting 1 result 1000 times. If the amount is small, you may not notice much different, however it is generally good practice and is less stressing on your database.

Comment: It is also easier to read and less typing when crafting the code! :)

Comment: Very true. Readability is also always something to strive for to save you or someone from headaches later on!